# Application Hanging on start

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, load, android-asynctask

I have a game application which is taking a very long time to load.  I used to have no lag when stating my game but now it is and I am suspecting something is hanging.  Is it possible that it is hanging due to the way I am loading the images?   Here is what I have:

In the onCreate() I have:

```
v = new SView(this);                      // Creates my new SurfaceView
a = new Accelerator();                    // Adds the accelerometer
new loadPhotos().execute("");             // Initiates the AsyncTask posted below
new handleStuff().execute("");            // starts the generation of the game map
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();   // Used to generate time lasted
setContentView(v);                        // Sets contentView to the SurfaceView


public class loadPhotos extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
@Override

protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.d(null, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!----------Starting Load-----------!!!!!!!!!1");
    player = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player);
    playerOpaque = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_opaque);
    livesBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lives);
    playerMissile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_missle);
    missileButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile_button);
    playerBullet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bullet);
    enemyBullet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy_bullet);
    enemyMissile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy_missle);
    enemy = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy);
    explosionBig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explosion);
    lastESpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_clearsky);
    cloudBM1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cloud1);
    cloudBM2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cloud2);
    Log.d(null, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!----------Ending Load-----------!!!!!!!!!1");
}
```

}

Here is my LogCat

```
03-22 10:03:50.546: D/(1220): !!!!!!!!!!!!!----------Starting Load-----------!!!!!!!!!1
03-22 10:03:50.596: D/(1220): !!!!!!!!!!!!!----------Ending Load-----------!!!!!!!!!1
03-22 10:03:50.616: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1220): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 10:03:50.646: W/SurfaceView(1220): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=true left=false top=false
03-22 10:03:50.656: D/(1220): !!!!!!!!!!!!!----------Starting Load-----------!!!!!!!!!1
03-22 10:03:50.706: D/dalvikvm(1220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2361K, 14% free 22198K/25543K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 28ms
03-22 10:03:50.726: D/(1220): !!!!!!!!!!!!!----------Ending Load-----------!!!!!!!!!1
03-22 10:03:50.746: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1220): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 10:04:18.096: D/dalvikvm(1220): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4756K, 28% free 20236K/27975K, paused 16ms, total 18ms
03-22 10:04:18.096: I/dalvikvm-heap(1220): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.131MB for 3686416-byte allocation
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat? I suspect that @codeMagic is right though, and you need to obtain your resources in the `onPreExecute` method, then operate on them in the `doInBackground`

Comment: use this link to use AsyncTask effectively http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I added the Logcat and also updated my AsyncTask Class

Comment: I suggest you to read the AsyncTask doc a bit more carefully cause you didn't understand what it does: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your `UI` resources throug `doInBackground` which you cannot do. This would need to be in `onPostExecute()` or other `Async` method but I'm not even sure you want/need an `AsyncTask` for this. You can just set your `images` using [ImageView methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and load them in a method of your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

try loading images as below
In a imageview
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);

This is much faster than loading through decoderesource.Each of your image loading have such a method.